# How to get one function to loop into another one and back again with different randints each time

Tags: python, text, random

So I have the following code:

```
    def monsterturn():
        global monster
        global playerhp
        turn = True
        print "Rolling for", monster, "...(14 or better to hit)"
        time.sleep(1)
        if r > 14:
            print r, "- The", monster, "hit you!"
            playerhp-=1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "Your HP:", playerhp
            if playerhp == 0:
                    turn = False
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print "YOU HAVE BEEN SLAIN."
            else:
                    turn = False
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    playerturn()
        elif r < 14:
            print r, "- The", monster, "missed you."
            turn = False
            playerturn()
    r = randrange(1, 21)
```

The function `playerturn()` is structured exactly like `monsterturn()`, except with the global variable monsterhp instead of playerhp, r2 instead of r, and dialogue for the player instead of the monster.  The problem is, it calculates a random integer once, and then keeps it, which often winds up with nobody hitting anyone, forever. How can I get it to calculate a different random integer every time?

Also, the function `playerturn()` is called, and at the end triggers `monsterturn()`, which triggers `playerturn()`, and so on, until somebody dies.

Comment: you shouldn't be using globals for any of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate r within the loop, instead of outside it.

You can also improve this greatly by factoring out the common material, so that monster and player have the same turn function. You'd do this by avoiding the reference to global variables and passing in the details that change (opponent's hitpoints, the message to print, and so forth)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just rethink your overall design, as this would cause you to run into issues. This is largely theoretical, but the longer your fight is, the deeper your call stack would become, in the end possibly resulting in a stack overflow (and also increased memory consumption; even if it continues to run fine).

Instead, I'd suggest you rework the functions to return a boolean value, whether the game should continue. You're then able to just loop as long as both functions return true, essentially meaning the game continues:

```
while playerturn() and monsterturn():
```

To make each hit/attack random, you'd reassign `r` a random value right before using it:

```
...
time.sleep(1)
r = randrange(1, 21)
if r > 14
    ...
```

Comment: `while playerturn() and monsterturn():`